# The potential field outside of a charged hemispherical shell

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law

I have a hemispherical *shell* of radius *a* held at potential Vo. Using Laplace's equation, with appropriate boundary conditions, I've been able to find the potential at any point **within** the hemisphere as: 
 U(r,$\Theta$) = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n (\frac ra)^n P_n[cos\Theta]$
where r is radial distance from the centre of the hemisphere
$\Theta$ is polar angle
$B_n$ is a coefficient determinable from initial conditions
$P_n$ is the legendre polynomial wrt cos$\Theta$
 How would one go about calculating the potential **outside** of this hemisphere at any point? Could the general result above be useful?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outside must have it's own boundary conditions. If no external fields are present, then the usual boundary conditions for such problems are:

Boundedness or 0 at infinity: $$U(r=\infty)=0$$

Continuity (of the potential) at the boundary : $$U(r=a^+)=U(r=a^-)$$

The calculation steps should be about the same as inside the hemisphere.